# Link colors don't match in both sites

Tags: discussion, design

Why are links blue in the main site, but orange in Meta? Was there a contrast issue? I wouldn't know, simply because I am a relatively new user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta uses a different .css style sheet to the main site, to make it easier to differentiate between them. This affects the colour of pretty much everything, including links.